# Creating generic container with more than one value

Tags: c#, collections

I am trying to create a generic container that contains more than one value:

I tried this:

```
List<char, string, List<int?>> my_list = new List<char, string, List<int?>>();
```

But I am obviosly getting an error message. Is there a way to create such collection?

Comment: You should create a new named type that logically represents those three values.  Create a list of that type.

Comment: That's right, [`Tuple.Item1`, `Tuple.Item2` and other `Tuple` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387150(v=vs.110).aspx) actually make the code less readable. It's best to simply spend a couple of minutes creating your own class. Hey, there are even Visual Studio snippets which do this if you're really lazy.

Comment: Also don't like the tuples cause I want my code to be as readable as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it this way:

```
struct structure
{
  public char a;
  public string b;
  public List<int?> c;
}

var list = new List<structure>();
```

Comment: Basically a sound approach, but there are several violations of basic C# coding style conventions. And yes, coding conventions are important when working in a team.

1. Custom type names should start with upper case letters.

2. Public class or struct members should also start with upper case letters.

3. Never use public fields, make them properties. Instead of `public char a` write `public char A { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Tuple<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 var list = new List<Tuple<char, string, List<int?>>>();
```